# Studying recreational math professionally?

Tags: mathematics, teaching

Are there professors who specialize in recreational types of math problems, or is my best bet to be a high school teacher and do recreational math in my free time?

Comment: Can you clarify the context behind the question? Your “best bet” to achieve what goal exactly?

Comment: Also, doing recreational math “professionally” is an oxymoron. What makes recreational math recreational is precisely that it is done for recreation and isn’t considered serious enough to do “professionally”. The boundary between serious and recreational math isn’t always clear and many professors have been known to cross it, but (with very rare exceptions) you won’t find mathematicians who do recreational math “for a living” as their primary specialty.

Comment: @DanRomik I strongly disagree. Taking recreational math _seriously_ can quickly lead to quite deep and difficult mathematics.  For example, I strongly suspect that at some level, Bill Thurston thought of most of his own work as recreational.

Comment: @JeffE what I said is true tautologically. Recreational math is, _by definition_, the set of topics that aren’t taken seriously by mainstream mathematicians. If ever some recreational math gets taken seriously and is found to lead to deep ideas (as you say happened with Thurston, and it’s happened to me several times so I’m certainly not claiming it doesn’t happen), it stops being classified as recreational. So, to emphasize, I’m not saying or suggesting that recreational mathematics _shouldn’t_ be studied seriously. (Therefore I disagree with your claim that you disagree with me :-)).

Comment: Go for what you enjoy. If you enjoy teaching, do high school teaching. If you enjoy research then do a PhD go down the professorial pathway.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of folks who do this, I think. I also think that a lot of them are members of the [Mathematical Association of America (MAA)](https://www.maa.org). That isn't their main focus, of course, but it would be a good source of contacts and information.

The [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recreational_mathematics) points to some other resources and maybe ways to contact people.

Whether you can make a career out of it depends on some things. At an R1 university, probably not, but maybe at a liberal arts college in the US. But it can be fun as a break from more serious(???) pursuits. And some aspects of it are certainly valid research topics. Game Theory, for example.

Comment: _At an R1 university, probably not_ — There are exceptions, of course; see John Conway at Princeton, Elwyn Berlekamp at Berkeley, or (more recently) Erik Demaine at MIT.  (Of course all three did/do deep research on non-recreational topics as well.)

Comment: Yes, @JeffE, they didn't "make a career of it".

Comment: Agree to disagree.  Making a career of something doesn't mean doing that thing exclusively.

Comment: @JeffE I agree with Buffy. John Conway isn’t a mathematician who “specialized in recreational types of math problems” per OP’s requirement.